# How to upload data(csv) from fileInput() shiny to S3?

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny

I am trying to upload a csv file which I am getting using fileInput() in shiny, to S3 bucket. But I am not able to do it from the shiny app itself.

I have tried the following code:

```
fileInput(
          "varData",
          "Please upload the data file.",
          multiple = FALSE,
          accept = c("text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv"))

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "ACCESS_KEY"
            "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "SECRET_KEY")

bucket_list_df() %>%
                dplyr::arrange(dplyr::desc(CreationDate)) %>%
                head()

put_object(input$varData, "file_name.csv", bucket = s3BucketName)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NULL
Warning: Error in parse_aws_s3_response: Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

Answer (score 0):

A turnaround solution was to create a temp file and write the data over there and then provide the location of that file in the `put_object()` call as follows:

```
tempFile <- as.data.frame(input$varData)
tempFileLoc <- "./temp_file.csv"
write.csv(tempFile, tempFileLoc)
```

And then run the put_object() as follows:

```
put_object(tempFileLoc, "file_name.csv", bucket = s3BucketName)
```

Then after the file is uploaded, the temp file created should be deleted.

Please also provide another alternative if there. Thanks in advance.